# How to get/set array element with reflection?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

Suppose I have

```
 int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
 Method method = // something

 // int element2 = array[2]; // non-reflection version 
 int element2 = (int) method.invoke(array, 2); // reflection version
```

How to fill `method` variable so that it get array element by index?

Comment: see my update please. I wish `Method` which returns element of an array

Comment: You cannot have a custom method which takes an array as the first argument.  You can do this with MethodHandles and closures, but not plain methods.  You could do `method.invoke(null, array, 2);` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### To answer question from title:

Java doesn't add new methods to arrays. Only methods available from arrays are those inherited from `Object` class, and there is none like `array.get(index)` which we could use via:

```
method.invoke(array,index)
```

That is why reflection package has utility class [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html), which contains methods like [`public static Object get​(Object array, int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,int)) and overloaded versions for primitive types like [`public static int getInt​(Object array, int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getInt(java.lang.Object,int)). It also contains corresponding `set(array, index, value)` methods.

With those we can write code like

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
int element2 = Array.getInt(array, 2);//reflective way
//or 
//int element2 = (int) Array.get(array, 2);//reflective way
System.out.println(element2);
```

---

#### BUT if goal of your question is to solve puzzle where we need to fill the blank and let below code work

```
 int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
 Method method = ...................// something

 // int element2 = array[2]; // non-reflection version 
 int element2 = (int) method.invoke(array, 2); // reflection version
```

then probably author of puzzle wants you to reflectively call `Arrays.get(array,index)`. In other words `method` should represent

```
Method method = Array.class.getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class, int.class);
```

But this would also require calling that method either on `Array.class` or on `null` (since it is static), so we would also need to modify

```
int element2 = (int) method.invoke(array, 2);
```

and add as first argument

```
int element2 = (int) method.invoke(Array.class, array, 2); // reflection version
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

OR

```
int element2 = (int) method.invoke(null, array, 2); // reflection version
                                   ^^^^
```

Comment: but OP is looking or `method.invoke()` otherwise this is also an answer `array[2]`

Comment: This is not `Method` and `get` is static. So, there is no (non-static) method which can obtain element of an array?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `List`

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

// create a List and populate
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : array) {
    list.add(i);
}

// use reflection method get/set on List
Method method = List.class.getDeclaredMethod("get", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE });
Object element2 = method.invoke(list, 2); // reflection version

System.out.println(element2); // output 3
```

- array doesn't have any `get` method. you can try with `List`.
- Finally you can get the array back from the `List`